# Mapbox Directions, custom route source

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-api-directions

Is it possible to retreive from Mapbox Directions API, routes (for specified points) which are restricted to my own routes source ? Now I receive good routes, but in my case, I have my own layers with pathes and sometimes Mapbox gives me route which is not part of my layer on the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to restrict the Mapbox router (which is based upon OSRM) to a certain set of streets.

What you can do, is to use [Mapbox Map Matching](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/map-matching/) to retrieve a route that has a set of coordinates (which you can pass in the MapMatching request) as waypoints.